# Consulta devuelve valores en SQL Server pero no retorna los mismo valores en Java

Tags: java, sql

Estoy ejecutando una consulta desde `java` hacia `SQL`, la cual se encarga de tomar los datos de la columna `Transferido` y los suma en una variable `QtyRecibido` con ciertos criterios definidos en la consulta, luego con otros criterios distintos resta los valores que se guardaron en la variable `QtyEnviado` y me devuelve el resultado de esa resta en una nueva columna definida como `QtyDisponible`.

Al ejecutar la consulta en la consola de `SQL Server` me devuelve los datos correctamente, pero al ejecutar la consulta en `Java`, esta no me retorna ninguna valor, he revisado detalladamente la sintaxis pero no logro encontrar donde esta el error.

```
SELECT re.QtyRecibido - en.QtyEnviado AS 'QtyDisponible' FROM(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Transferido),0 ) AS 'QtyRecibido' FROM Produccion.Transferido 
WHERE  WO = 'W001111'AND AreaRecibe = 'AOI' AND Estado = 'Completo') re ,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Transferido),0) AS 'QtyEnviado' FROM Produccion.Transferido 
WHERE WO = 'W001111' AND AreaEntrega = 'AOI') en
```

No tiene errores de sintaxis en SQL Server ni en java tampoco (al parecer), solo que el valor que devuelve en SQL no lo retorna en java, retorna null.

Esta es la consulta ejecutada en JAVA:

```
'String consulta = "SELECT re.QtyRecibido - en.QtyEnviado AS 
'QtyDisponible' FROM(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Transferido),0 ) AS 
'QtyRecibido' FROM Produccion.Transferido WHERE  WO = 
'"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"'"
+"AND AreaRecibe = '"+LineaActual()+"' AND Estado = 'Completo') re 
,(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Transferido),0) AS 'QtyEnviado' FROM 
  Produccion.Transferido WHERE WO = '"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"' 
 AND 
  AreaEntrega = '"+LineaActual()+"') en";'
```

La imagen muestra arriba los valores que tiene la tabla actualmente, y la parte de abajo el valor que retorna luego de realizar la consulta, el cual es correcto.

[image: La imagen muestra la información que contiene actualmente la base de datos]

Comment: peudes poner el codigo donde ejecutas la consulta?

Comment: Listo, ya lo agregué

Comment: podrias hacer antes de ejecutar la consulta un `System.out.printl(consulta)` para ver como va formada?

Comment: El valor que obtengo de la consulta lo estoy guardando en un array, luego hago un JOption.Pane.ShowMessageDialog que me muestre lo que obtuvo el array pero el valor que retorna es null, tambien lo corrí en modo Debug en netbeans y de igual forma retorna null.

Comment: NO, antes de ejecutar la consuta imprime en consola la varaible consulta asi vera como va formada

Comment: ya lo hice, y este es el valor que devuelve "consulta" antes de la ejecucion de la consulta: `SELECT re.QtyRecibido - en.QtyEnviado AS 'QtyDisponible' FROM(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Transferido),0 ) AS 'QtyRecibido' FROM Produccion.Transferido 
WHERE  WO = 'W001111'AND AreaRecibe = 'AOI' AND Estado = 'Completo') re ,(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Transferido),0) AS 'QtyEnviado' FROM Produccion.Transferido 
WHERE WO = 'W001111' AND AreaEntrega = 'AOI') en`

Comment: No comprendo, si la consulta se forma con los valores correctos, porque no se ejecuta correctamente ni devuelve nada?

Comment: Why do you type `string consulta`?

Comment: consulta is a String Variable in java, I just call the String "consulta" in the try catch procedure in order to use it during the query